# Displaying dates in x axis of Bokeh Area plot

Tags: python, bokeh

Passing my dataframe like this can display plot but not when I specify `x` to correspond to my Date column. Can you suggest what might be the problem here? I tried converting my Date column into `string`, `datetime` and other formats with no success.

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.charts import output_file, Area, defaults
from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook
output_notebook()

xf = pd.DataFrame([{'Cat1': 112.04, 'Cat2': 0.0, 'REDUCED_DATE': '2011-12'},
 {'Cat1': 359.57449999999994, 'Cat2': 579.35, 'REDUCED_DATE': '2012-01'},
 {'Cat1': 376.99000000000007, 'Cat2': 552.64, 'REDUCED_DATE': '2012-02'},
 {'Cat1': 416.86000000000007, 'Cat2': 543.35, 'REDUCED_DATE': '2012-03'},
 {'Cat1': 320.5847000000001, 'Cat2': 543.35, 'REDUCED_DATE': '2012-04'},
 {'Cat1': 521.0349999999999, 'Cat2': 553.33, 'REDUCED_DATE': '2012-05'},
 {'Cat1': 330.84, 'Cat2': 667.94, 'REDUCED_DATE': '2012-06'}])

xf["Date"] =xf.REDUCED_DATE.astype(str)
area1 = Area(xf,y=["Cat1","Cat2"], title="Area chart", legend="top_left",
             xlabel="Date",ylabel="Amount",stack=True)

show(area1, notebook_handle=True)
```

[image]

Passing Date as `x` column does not display any data at all:

```
xf["Date"] =xf.REDUCED_DATE.astype(str)
area1 = Area(xf, x="REDUCED_DATE", y=["Cat1","Cat2"], title="Area chart",
             legend="top_left",xlabel="Date",ylabel="Amount",stack=True)

show(area1, notebook_handle=True)
```

[image]

Comment: why don't you create a simple example with imports and data values so that we can easily help you. This way you might find the solution to the problem yourself, or me or somebody else.

Comment: @PabloReyes thanks you are absolutely right. I added data and imports for easier replication of the problem.

Comment: Apparently there is a bug that prevents the date strings to display as tick labels. In my answer I provide a workaround that might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is a bug in `bokeh.charts.Area` and if confirmed it should be reported in the  [bokeh repository](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh). I am using bokeh version 0.12.4 and there is a curiosity about the string values to be used as xaxis tick labels (REDUCED_DATE in the present example). If the third value is '2' and the fourth value starts with '3'(or 4,5,...9) then Area chart shows ok, otherwise no Area chart is shown (as in the question):

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.charts import output_file, Area
from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook
output_notebook()

xf = pd.DataFrame([
     {'Cat1': 112.04, 'Cat2': 0.0, 'REDUCED_DATE': '2011-12'},
     {'Cat1': 359.57449999999994, 'Cat2': 579.35, 'REDUCED_DATE': '2012-01'},
     {'Cat1': 376.99000000000007, 'Cat2': 552.64, 'REDUCED_DATE': '2'},
     {'Cat1': 416.86000000000007, 'Cat2': 543.35, 'REDUCED_DATE': '3'},
     {'Cat1': 320.5847000000001, 'Cat2': 543.35, 'REDUCED_DATE': '2012-04'},
     {'Cat1': 521.0349999999999, 'Cat2': 553.33, 'REDUCED_DATE': '2012-05'},
     {'Cat1': 330.84, 'Cat2': 667.94, 'REDUCED_DATE': '2012-06'}
])

area1 = Area(xf, x="REDUCED_DATE", y=["Cat1","Cat2"], title="Area chart",
             legend="top_left",xlabel="Date",ylabel="Amount",stack=True)
show(area1, notebook_handle=True)
```

The output:
[image]

A workaround that worked for me is using `bokeh.plotting.figure` to create a figure with `x_range` defined by `bokeh.models.FactorRange` and adding `patches` glyphs:

```
import pandas as pd
import bokeh.plotting
from bokeh.charts import output_file
from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook
output_notebook()

xf = pd.DataFrame([
     {'Cat1': 112.04, 'Cat2': 0.0, 'REDUCED_DATE': '2011-12'},
     {'Cat1': 359.57449999999994, 'Cat2': 579.35, 'REDUCED_DATE': '2012-01'},
     {'Cat1': 376.99000000000007, 'Cat2': 552.64, 'REDUCED_DATE': '2012-02'},
     {'Cat1': 416.86000000000007, 'Cat2': 543.35, 'REDUCED_DATE': '2012-03'},
     {'Cat1': 320.5847000000001, 'Cat2': 543.35, 'REDUCED_DATE': '2012-04'},
     {'Cat1': 521.0349999999999, 'Cat2': 553.33, 'REDUCED_DATE': '2012-05'},
     {'Cat1': 330.84, 'Cat2': 667.94, 'REDUCED_DATE': '2012-06'}
])

# getting the coordinates of the patches:
nvals = xf.shape[0]
accum = pd.np.zeros(nvals)
vals = []
for cat in ['Cat1','Cat2']:
    prev_accum = accum.copy()
    accum += xf[cat].get_values()
    vals += [pd.np.concatenate((prev_accum,accum[::-1]))]

p = bokeh.plotting.figure(
        x_range=bokeh.models.FactorRange(factors=list(xf["REDUCED_DATE"]),offset=-1))
p.patches(xs=[range(nvals)+range(nvals-1,-1,-1)], ys=[vals[0]],
                color=['#f22c40'],alpha=0.8 ,legend='Cat1')
p.patches(xs=[range(nvals)+range(nvals-1,-1,-1)], ys=[vals[1]],
                color=['#5ab738'],alpha=0.8 ,legend='Cat2')
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 3.4142/4
p.legend[0].location = 'top_left'
p.xaxis.axis_label = "Date"
p.yaxis.axis_label = "Amount"
show(p)
```

The output here is the correct one:

[image]

**UPDATE bokeh version 0.12.16**

`offset` no longer supported in `FactorRange` in the latest versions of bokeh. In the following code (tested in version 0.12.16) I am using `datetime` as the x axis values. Also inspired in the following codes: [brewer.py](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/brewer.html) and [github issue #6376](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/6376):

```
import pandas as pd
import bokeh.plotting
from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook

xf = pd.DataFrame([
     {'Cat1': 112.04, 'Cat2': 0.0, 'REDUCED_DATE': '2011-12'},
     {'Cat1': 359.57449999999994, 'Cat2': 579.35, 'REDUCED_DATE': '2012-01'},
     {'Cat1': 376.99000000000007, 'Cat2': 552.64, 'REDUCED_DATE': '2012-02'},
     {'Cat1': 416.86000000000007, 'Cat2': 543.35, 'REDUCED_DATE': '2012-03'},
     {'Cat1': 320.5847000000001, 'Cat2': 543.35, 'REDUCED_DATE': '2012-04'},
     {'Cat1': 521.0349999999999, 'Cat2': 553.33, 'REDUCED_DATE': '2012-05'},
     {'Cat1': 330.84, 'Cat2': 667.94, 'REDUCED_DATE': '2012-06'}
])

def stacked(df,N=2):
    df_top = df.iloc[:,0:N].cumsum(axis=1) # accumulates first N columns
    df_bottom = df_top.shift(axis=1).fillna({'Cat1': 0})[::-1]
    df_stack = pd.concat([df_bottom, df_top], ignore_index=True)
    return df_stack

dates  = [pd.datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%m') for x in xf['REDUCED_DATE']]
x2 = np.hstack((dates[::-1], dates))
areas = stacked(xf)

source = bokeh.models.ColumnDataSource(dict(
    xs=[x2] * areas.shape[1],
    ys=[areas[c].values for c in areas],
    color=['#f22c40','#5ab738'],
    label=['Cat1','Cat2']
))

p = bokeh.plotting.figure( x_axis_type='datetime')
p.patches( xs='xs', ys='ys', color='color', legend='label', source=source,alpha=0.8)
p.xaxis.formatter = bokeh.models.formatters.DatetimeTickFormatter(months=["%Y-%m"])
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 3.4142/4
p.legend.location = 'top_left'
p.xaxis.axis_label = "Date"
p.yaxis.axis_label = "Amount"

output_notebook()
show(p)
```

Comment: Have you tried this with latest version of bokeh, plots empty graph. Any pointers?